# error 500 after inserting the data to mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vue.js

Im build Vue app with mongo and express.
I have  bug after sending the post request to mongo.

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
at createError (createError.js?2d83:16)
at settle (settle.js?467f:18)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?b50d:77)
```

After all I can still make this post request but it does not redirect me. I need to change route in my frontend app and then I can see this posted data. 
I think the problem is somewhere inside my post route setup and mongoose model.

Post route:

```
router.route('/').post(function (req, res) {
let post = new Post(req.body);
post.save()
post.comments.push(Comment)
  .then(() => {
    res.status(200).json({});
  })
  .catch(() => {
    res.status(400).send("unable to save to database");
  })
```

})

Post model :

```
const Post = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String
  },
  text: {
    type: String
  },
  img: String,
  price: Number,
  postType: String,
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
},{
    collection: 'posts'
});
```

Comment model:

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  text: String,
  rating: Number,
  author: String,

});
```

Sorry for my English. I hope you understand me

Comment: Ok, I'm idiot. I delete this line post.comments.push(Comment) and everything works fine... I hate myself :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An error 500 means Internal Server Error. So, it's probably not coming from Vue, rather from the express API. Have you checked the logs from Express?